# How to change the color of a single JProgressBar in Nimbus?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jprogressbar, nimbus

I'm trying to change the color of a single JProgressBar in Nimbus LAF (Look And Feel). This solution does work, but it changes the colors of ALL JProgressBars :/

```
    UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
    defaults.put("nimbusOrange",defaults.get("nimbusBase"));
```

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174420/change-colors-for-jprogressbar-with-nimbus) is another solution to change the color for each JProgressBar individually:

```
    progress = new JProgressBar();
    UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
    defaults.put("ProgressBar[Enabled].backgroundPainter", new MyPainter());
    progress.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", Boolean.TRUE);
    progress.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
```

Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I don't know where to find the libary for "MyPainter()". So I tried replacing this method (without knowing what I'm doing) with "defaults.get("nimbusBase")" and "Color.red". Didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.can you please to indicate which one from

```
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.background", Color.orange);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.foreground", Color.blue);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionBackground", Color.red);
UIManager.put("ProgressBar.selectionForeground", Color.green);
```

notice valid `UIDefaults` for `MetalLookAndFeel`,

2.then please to search equivalent in [Nimbus Defaults](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html#primary)

3.then to try override the [JProgressBar with logics and with this Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788379/714968)

Comment: +1, still many a things I have to learn from the Link you gave me once regarding this thingy. I didn't knew it's that simple :-)

Comment: that could be terrible, till moment, when you know where to use standard Color (XxxRenderer), when putNimbusColor (non-compond) JComponents and for Compoun & JButtons JComponents...

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful reply. Everything works now for me. :D

For any future readers: If your compiler is missing "com.sun.java.swing.Painter.class" and/or "javax.swing.Painter.class" you can [download](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org-netbeans-swing/org-netbeans-swing-tabcontrol.jar.zip) it here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgnetbeansswingtabcontroljar.htm

Comment: @Matthieu not sure if I understand correctly, in linked post is used FillPainter, which only fill available rectangle with one color, for nicer look is there required to use GradientPaint in Painter

Comment: @mKorbel, sorry, I got confused with my too-many search on the subject with the too-many different answers. It's clearer with your post, hvala! :)