# Java JProgressBar setting colour

Tags: java, jprogressbar

I have a JProgressBar drawn on a JPanel to show a static value.  I can get everything working fine apart from one thing, the colour.  If I use

```
ProgressBarServ1.setForeground(Color.red);
ProgressBarServ1.setBackground(Color.blue);
```

then I get a red, or any colour I pick, percentage number in the progress bar (that's ok) but I don't get a blue bar.  I always get a mid brown/bronze colour.

I've had a good look through google and there doesn't seem to be a good answer.

The duplicate you point to doesn't actually give an answer, just discussion!

Martin.

Comment: Also check this topic, it has additional solutions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802887/nimbus-lf-change-background-color-of-progress-bar/11803010#11803010

Comment: I'd read that one and I understand that the UIManager.put commands are effectively changing the default values.  But where do I put the UIManager code as I cannot get it to make any changes!

Comment: You'd better place this code before any UI components get created.

Comment: Placed them into public MainJFrame as the first entry and before initComponents().  But still no colour change.